# Rounding an int number to another int number

Tags: java, int, rounding

```
while(potatosconeflour <= c1) {
    potatosconeflour = potatosconeflour + potatosconeflour;
}
```

I used a while loop which does not work after inputting the number 24.I am trying to round an int number to another int number. E.g., I want to round any number to a multiple of 8.

E.g: rounding 1 to 8, 13 to 16, 23 to 24

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Please show us some more of your code - the current excerpt isn't sufficient to find the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'd divide the source number by the number to round it by (caution: cast it to a `double` so you don't use integer division!) use `Math.ceil` to round the result upwards, and then multiply it back by the same number:

```
public static int roundToMultiple(int toRound, int roundBy) {
    return roundBy * (int) Math.ceil((double)toRound / roundBy);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can't use Math.round, roundToMultiple(1,8) will return 0

Comment: Math.round rounds to the nearest int, so 1/8 will get rounded to 0 and then 0 * 8 = 0. You need to use Math.ceil instead

Comment: @Marcelo you're right. The OP used the term round, although he actually meant ceiling, which threw me off. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round to the *nearest* multiple of 8, that's just `((i + 3) / 8) * 8`.  (That rounds down if it's `8n + 4`.  If you want to round up from half, use `i + 4` instead of `i + 3`.  If you want to round "all the way up," `9` to `16`, use `i + 7`.)

Comment: thanks for your help. what would i use if i wanted to round to a multiple of 225

Comment: In general it's just `((i + (n/2)) / n) * n`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulo operator (`%`), which returns the remainder, then add the subtraction of the remainder from `8` to your number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 13;
    int rem = i % 8 > 0 ? i % 8 : 8;

    i += 8 - rem;

    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Outputs: `16`

Comment: Thanks for the help. however if i input the number 8 it rounds up to 16. how can i get it so the number 8 will stay on 8 and not round up to 16???

Comment: @user7327674 ahh I forgot to check if `i` was already a multiple of 8.

Comment: @user7327674 I updated my answer but it throws a conditional into the mix, your better off using [Mureinik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41272097/1241334) or [Louis Wasserman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41272130/1241334).